# Cannot find syntaxerror

Tags: python, string, syntax

```
msg = ('Here is your breakdown of your most used words: \n\n'
           'Word | Times Used'
           '\n:--:|:--:'
           '\n' + str(keys[0]).capitalize() + '|' + str(values[0])
           '\n*'* + str(keys[1]).capitalize() + '|' + str(values[1])
           '\n' + str(keys[2]).capitalize() + '|' + str(values[2])
           '\n' + str(keys[3]).capitalize() + '|' + str(values[3])
           '\n' + str(keys[4]).capitalize() + '|' + str(values[4])
           '\n' + str(keys[5]).capitalize() + '|' + str(values[5])
           '\n' + str(keys[6]).capitalize() + '|' + str(values[6])
           '\n' + str(keys[7]).capitalize() + '|' + str(values[7])
           '\n' + str(keys[8]).capitalize() + '|' + str(values[8])
           '\n' + str(keys[9]).capitalize() + '|' + str(values[9]))
```

I am getting a syntax error where the ' surrounded by *'s is.

Comment: What is the error message?

Comment: "There's an error in your program: Invalid syntax"

Comment: So what is msg? A long string, or a tuple of two strings?. Look at the first two three strings. Either you are missing comma or a plus.

Comment: I FORGOT THE PLUS AT THE END OF THE LINE! Thanks so much.

Comment: Add '+' at the end of third line.

Comment: @rajpy the *fourth* line is actually the first one that needs a `+`. Adjacent string literals are parsed as a single string.

Comment: @ivc: you are right. Thanks for correcting.

Answer (score 2):

The line that is wrong is `'\n*'* + str(keys[1]).capitalize() + '|' + str(values[1])`

Of course its a syntax error after `*` you got a `+`.

`'\n*'* + str(keys[1]).capitalize() + '|' + str(values[1])`

should be (no `*`)

`'\n*' + str(keys[1]).capitalize() + '|' + str(values[1])`

Comment: no that * is just to show where the error is

Comment: Never trust a compiler's idea of where an error is. It can only tell you where *it* got confused in parsing your program, not where you actually made a mistake. The actual error is usually somewhere before that. In this case, you've got strings next to each other without a + to concatenate them or a , to make them tuples. How to fix that depends on what you want.

Comment: @LeeDanielCrocker: That doesn't *need* fixing (although it would be much more readable in this case if it were done differently), it's a feature Python takes from C -- those string literals are automatically concatenated at compile time. for example `'foo' 'bar' == 'foobar'`. The problem is when string non-literals are next to string literals with no operator to join them, as lvc points out.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of finding this error, how about rewriting it a bit cleanly?

```
msg = """Here is your breakdown of your most used words:
         Word | Times Used
         :--:|:--:"""

for k,v in somedict:
    msg += "\n{}|{}".format(k.capitalize(),v)

print(msg)
```

Answer (score 1):

This is one of the rare cases where a SyntaxError is almost exactly where a compiler says it is:

```
msg = ('Here is your breakdown of your most used words: \n\n'
           'Word | Times Used'
           '\n:--:|:--:'
           '\n' + str(keys[0]).capitalize() + '|' + str(values[0])
```

Up to here you're fine. If you close the brackets here and remove the rest, this will parse.

The problem is that after this, you have another string literal: `'\n' + ...`. You can have two string *literals* next to each other without a problem (Python treats them as a single string), but at this stage Python sees:

```
str(values([0])) '\n'
```

which is always a syntax error. You need an operator between these, most likely `+`. The strings next to each other trick *only* works with literals. For example, you can do:

```
>>> 'fred' 'flintstone'
'fredflintstone'
```

but not:

```
>>> x = 'fred'
>>> x 'flintstone'
  File "<stdin>", line 1
    x 'flintstone'
                 ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Answer (score -1):

In python, you need escape each line with back slash(¥), and each string is needed to join with + operator.

Witch is like following,

```
str = "abc" ¥
      + "def" ¥
      + "ghi"
```

Comment: False, on both counts. You don't need to explicitly join lines that are surrounded by `()` (or `[]` or `{}`) as in the question; Python parses anything between those as one long line. You also don't need to explicitly concatenate string literals - two next two each other (separated only by whitespace) are parsed as a single string.

Comment: I'm sorry, I have misunderstanding about syntax. Thank you for your advise.